# Не все заголовки приходят в объекте ответа

Tags: reactjs, node.js, json, api, axios

Есть такая проблема: на сервере я установил заголовок x-total-count. Если делаю запрос, то заголовок приходит, но виден он только если смотреть через devtools. А если же выводить объект ответа в консоль, то там можно увидеть только такие заголовки: Content-type и Content-Lenght. В чём может быть проблема. Я делал запросы на друге апи и там все заголовки приходили, а у меня не приходят.

В консоли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В devtools:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сервере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#access-control-expose-headers

Comment: Как ты смотришь заголовки в скрипте?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, надо установить заголовок `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` и добавить туда нужные заголовки.

Как-то так:

```
async getAllWarranties (req, res, next) {
    try {
        const {page, limit} = req.query
        const {id} = req.user
        const data = await WarrantyService.getAllWarranties(id, page, limit)

        res.set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'x-total-count')
        res.set('x-total-count', data.totalCount);

        return res.json(data.warranties)
    } catch (e) {
        next(e)
    }
}
```